# Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of continuous functions from the reals to the reals. And let $\sup{|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|} \leq \frac1{\min(m,n)}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of continuous functions from the reals to the reals. And let $\sup{|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|} \leq \frac{1}{\min(m,n)}$

Prove there is a continuous functions $f$ such that 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sup{|f_n(x)-f(x)|}=0$$

Start: I think this is an $\epsilon/3$ proof. 
Let $\epsilon >0$ and let $a$ be a real number. Since each $f_n$ is continuous, there is a $\delta$ such that $|x-a|$ implies $|f_n(x)-f_n(a)|<\epsilon/3$

Also from the sup norm above, we observe that as $n \rightarrow \infty$ we have $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)| < \epsilon/3$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know that  $f_n$ converges iff it is Cauchy?

Comment: Is this sequence $(f_n)$ Cauchy?

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given, let $N>1/\varepsilon$. Then, if $m,n>N$ we have that $\min(n,m)>1/\varepsilon$. So we can make $$\frac 1 {\min(n,m)}$$ as small as we like.

Then, $\sup|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<\varepsilon$, provided $m,n$ are large.

We know that a sequence $f_n$ converges uniformly if it is uniformly Cauchy, i.e $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|$ can be made smaller than any $\varepsilon>0$, provided $n,m>N$ for some $N$ taken independently of $x$.

Note that $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\leq \sup |f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<\varepsilon$. Thus $f_n$ converges.

Comment: You mean $\frac{1}{\min(n,m)}$ is Cauchy, right?

Comment: A sequence can be Cauchy, but in what sense is $\min(n,m)$ Cauchy? Ditto for $\sup |f_n-f_m|$

Comment: @zhw. Ugh, brain lag. It was definitely too late. I believe this is fine now.