# Understanding a previously asked question about existence of a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

I need clarification on how to write a clear proof of a question previously by another person.I am trying to understand this problem, and I would appreciate it you could tell me if I have misunderstandings in the following proof. This proof is mainly a reconstruction of the hints/ideas discussed here: ([Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of continuous functions from the reals to the reals. And let $\sup{|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|} \leq \frac1{\min(m,n)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1772126/let-f-n-be-a-sequence-of-continuous-functions-from-the-reals-to-the-reals-a))

Problem: Suppose $f_1,f_2,..,$ is a sequence of continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $$sup \{|f_m(x)-f_n(x)|:x\in \mathbb{R}\} \leq \frac{1}{min\{m,n\}}$$ for all integers $m,n$. Prove that there exists a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $$lim_{n \to \infty}(sup\{|f(x)-f_n(x)|:x \in \mathbb{R}\})=0.$$.

Proof: Let $\epsilon >0$ be given. By the Archimedean Property we can find a natural number N such that $N>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$. Then if $m,n>N$, we have that  $min(m,n)>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$. In particular, for $n,m >N$

$$sup \{|f_m(x)-f_n(x)|:x\in \mathbb{R}\} \leq \frac{1}{min\{m,n\}}<\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}=\epsilon$$. Hence $f_n$ is Cauchy. By the uniform Cauchy Criterion, $f_n$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$, that is, given an $\epsilon>0$, we can choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n>N$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$ implies $$|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$$. Moreover, since each $f_N$ is continuous, we can choose $\delta>0$ such that $|x-a|<\delta$, and $x\in \mathbb{R}$ implies $$|f_N(x)-f_N(a)| <\frac{\epsilon}{3}$$. Then note

$$|f(x)-f(a)|\leq |f(x)-f_N(x)|+|f_N(x)-f_N(a)|+|f_N(a)-f(a)|<\epsilon$$. Hence

there exists a continuos function f such that $$lim_{n \to \infty}(sup\{|f(x)-f_n(x)|:x \in \mathbb{R}\})=0.$$.

My questions:

Is it enough to show that $f_n$ converges uniformly?( Since if $f_n$ converges uniformly and each $f_n$ is continuous that implies that $f_n$ converges to a continuous function f).

Does showing that $f_n$ converges uniformly automatically proofs the existence of this continuous function?

Comment: Your problem requires you to prove that uniformly Cauchy sequences of continuous functions have continuous limits; this requires a little estimation, it is not free.

Comment: @Ian The OP seems to know that fact already.

Comment: I edited my proof based on what you said, though I am not sure if that is sufficient or if i did it correctly.

Comment: Your argument works, but I'd like to point out where *exactly* you had to use uniformity to make this "$\epsilon/3$ argument" work, in case you missed it. With just pointwise convergence, you could fix $N$ depending on $x$ so that $|f(x)-f_N(x)|$ was small. Similarly, for this particular $N$, you could choose $\delta>0$ so that $|f_N(x)-f_N(a)|$ is small too. Where uniformity is invoked is in using the *same* $N$ to control $|f_N(a)-f(a)|$. Without uniformity, you might need a bigger $N$ to control this third term, which could result in a smaller $\delta$ for the second term, etc. forever.

Comment: This exact same issue arises again in the proof Arzela-Ascoli theorem, although in that setting it is resolved in a slightly different way.

Comment: I'm confused about this question. In your original post, now edited, you seemed to know, and use, two facts: i) A uniformly Cauchy sequence of functions is uniformly convergent; ii) if $f$ is the limit of a uniformly convergent sequence of continuous functions, then $f$ is continuous. Why are you now proving ii)?

Comment: i) If my understanding is correct, I needed to show that $f_n$ is Cauchy,that is, I needed to show that $\frac{1}{min(m,n)} <\epsilon$. Once I established that, I was able to use the uniform Cauchy criterion, which gave me uniformly convergence. ii) I am proving this because I needed to show that a sequence of continuous functions converges to a continuous function. Apparently is not enough to just say this without proving it.

Comment: Breaking things down into three basic steps: 1. A uniformly Cauchy sequence is pointwise Cauchy. A pointwise Cauchy sequence is pointwise convergent (this is just because $\mathbb{R}$ is complete). 2. A uniformly Cauchy sequence converges uniformly to its pointwise limit. This follows by writing down the Cauchy criterion and sending just $m$ to infinity while holding $n$ fixed. 3. The uniform limit of a sequence sequence of continuous functions is continuous. This follows from the "$\epsilon/3$ argument" that you have written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to both questions is yes. Because if $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $|f(x)-f_n(x)| < \frac\epsilon2$, for every $n > N$.

Since $f_n$ is continuous, $\forall p \in \mathbb{R}$, $\exists \delta > 0$ such that if $|x-p|<\delta$ we have $|f_n(x) - f_n(p) < \frac\epsilon2$.

Hence, if $|x-p| < \delta$, we have $$|f(x)-f(p)| = |f(x)-f_n(x) + f_n(p)-f(p)| \leq |f(x)-f_n(x)| + |f_n(p)-f(p)| \leq \frac\epsilon2 + \frac\epsilon2 = \epsilon.$$

Therefore, $f$ is continuous. Now, since $f_n \to f$ uniformly, given $\epsilon > 0$, take $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that, for every $m,n > N$, $$\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |f_n(x)-f_m(x)| < \frac\epsilon2.$$
Taking the limit $m \to \infty$, $$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} |f_n(x)-f(x)| \leq \frac\epsilon2 < \epsilon.$$

Therefore, $\lim_n \sup_x |f_n(x) - f(x)| = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

since for each $x\in\mathbb R$,

we have

$\forall m,n>N\;\; |f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<\epsilon$

this means that $ (f_n(x))_n$ is a Cauchy sequence.

put $lim_{n\to+\infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$

then

$$\forall m>N$$

$\forall x\in\mathbb R \;\; \forall n>N\;\; |f_n(x)-f_\color{red}{m}(x)|<\epsilon$

and by passage to the limit when $\color{red}{m}\to+\infty$, we get

$\forall n>N\;\;\forall x\in\mathbb R\;\;|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$

this proves the uniform convergence.